# Blank result for some columns when php mysql_query, works in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, phpmyadmin

I've run into a problem that is making me go a bit crazy. I have imported some csv data into a table in my phpadmin database and am now using a php script with `mysql_query()` to run a simple select query on the database and convert the result into json format - e.g. `SELECT clients FROM TABLE 29`.

Basically, some of the columns in the table result in a json string after passing them through `mysql_query()` but others simply return a blank. I have fiddled for hours now and can't figure out why this is. The last bit of my code looks like this:

```
$myquery = "SELECT `clients` FROM `TABLE 29`";

$query = mysql_query($myquery) or die(mysql_error());

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Could it be something about the data in the table? I'm at a loss.

thank you!

UPDATE: the length of the strings in the column `clients` seems to be having an effect. When I replace all the text with something shorter (e.g. `aaa` instead of something like `company name 111 - 045 - project name - currency - etc`) it works. However, I need it to be able to handle long strings as I want it to just take whatever users happen to import into it... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No, its not about the table, its about how you loop them. Example:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { // While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
mysql_close($server);
exit;
```

Note: mysql is depreacted and no longer maintained. Use the improved version of the mysql extension which is mysqli or use PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this doesn't do the trick. Whichever approach to looping I use, some columns work in the SELECT statement while others do not. E.g. column `Budget` works but column `clients` does not. So it must be something else. I'll look into mysqli/PDO but am unsure whether that is a possible reason for the problem or not.

Comment: @AndreLing you really have a table named `TABLE 29`? (with space?)

Comment: yes. I just changed it to `capacity` - still the same problem.

Comment: I only seem to face this problems with tables that I import after saving an excel file as csv... and it only seems to affect some columns.

Comment: digg utf and mysql memory limit also

Answer (score 0):

After checking all the rows of the data I discovered that the source of the problem was a 'é' - yes, an 'e' with an accent. Once I replaced it with a regular 'e' the problem went away. So much lost time for something so tiny :(